# How debug Drupal 8 errors

Tags: debugging

How should I debug OOP level errors in Drupal8? Error messages and backtrace seem to be useless.

I have installed the **pants** module locally on the latest Drupal 8 environment. And got an error. Now, I know it's because of the Pants module, because it worked fine before I installed it. But the problem is that the error message and the backtrace are completely useless in debugging this problem. Please see the image attached.

Am I missing something? How this problem should be debugged, given the non-descriptive messages?

[image]

Comment: Currently we don't get any stack trace by default. we have to set below config in settings.php

$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';

Comment: I have seen a few cryptic errors too that aren't obvious right away.  I've had a lot of success with Netbeans and XDebug together.  Several development environments (IDEs) integrate with xdebug, which would allow you to go to (in your case) line 275 of file /var/www/d8/drupal/core/lib/Drupal.php to see what non-object is calling the get() method.  These IDE tools will give you the stack trace at that point and will allow you to navigate down the stack to see the origin of the problem.